# Unexpected value 'LoginRoutingModule' imported by the module 'LoginModule'

Tags: angular

Hello as part of Angular 2 learning project I am creating a test app.

I am trying to eagerly load one of the Module called LoginModule however I get following error 
Unexpected value 'LoginRoutingModule' imported by the module 'LoginModule'

I tried to refer other questions where error message is similar to above however nothing has helped me yet.

It would be great if someone could help me solve the issue.

My directory structure is as follows

[image]

login.module.ts is like this

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { LoginRoutingModule, loginRoutableComponents } from './login-routing.module';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        LoginRoutingModule ],
    declarations: [ loginRoutableComponents ],
})
export class LoginModule{ }
```

login-routing.module.ts is as follows

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
];

NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(routes) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ],
})
export class LoginRoutingModule{ }

export const loginRoutableComponents = [
    LoginComponent
];
```

app.module.ts is as follows

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

import { ToastModule } from './core/toast/toast.module';
import { ModalModule } from './core/modal/modal.module';
import { SpinnerModule } from './core/spinner/spinner.module';

import { CharacterModule } from './characters/character.module';
import { DashboardModule } from './dashboard/dashboard.module';
import { VehiclesModule } from './vehicles/vehicles.module';

import { LoginModule } from './login/login.module';

import { AppRoutingModule, appRoutableComponents } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule,
                  FormsModule,
                  RouterModule,
                  ToastModule,
                  ModalModule,
                  SpinnerModule,
                  DashboardModule,
                  CharacterModule,
                  VehiclesModule,
                  LoginModule,
                  AppRoutingModule
                ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,
                  appRoutableComponents,
                ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts is as follows

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found.component';
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'dashboard' },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
]


@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

export const appRoutableComponents = [
    PageNotFoundComponent
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the @ before NgModule in this component

```
login-routing.module.ts is as follows

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
];
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@NgModule({
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(routes) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ],
})
export class LoginRoutingModule{ }

export const loginRoutableComponents = [
    LoginComponent
];
```

Comment: Silly me to make such a mistake

Comment: Cool. Happy to help you :)